# Как сборщик преобразует значения?

Tags: css, сборка

У меня есть css-свойство с функцией calc:

```
font-size: calc((100vh - 389px)/100/8.92)
```

Сборщик преобразует значение этого свойства в такое:

```
font-size: calc(.112108vh - .436099px)
```

Как сборщик вычисляет эти значения?

Comment: Какой сборщик-то?

Comment: Впрочем, даже независимо от сброщика непонятно, что вам непонятно — если взять любой калькулятор и вбить в него 100/100/8.92 и 389/100/8.92, то получатся эти же самые числа